# Spring singleton with property

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I would like to create a singleton that contains the MAC address of the system it is running on, based on a supplied network interface.

I have written the following code:

```
public class NodeMac {

    private static final String INSTANCE = getMacAddress();

    private static String networkInterfaceName;

    @Value("${machine.network.interface}")
    public void setNetworkInterfaceName(String networkInterfaceName) {
        NodeMac.networkInterfaceName = networkInterfaceName;
    }

    private NodeMac() { }

    public static String getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static String getMacAddress() {
        try {
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByName(networkInterfaceName);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (SocketException | NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Failed to extract MAC address for network interface with name " + networkInterfaceName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

And in application.properties:

```
machine.network.interface=eno1
```

However, I can't find any way to get the property value that contains the name of the network interface. It is always null, no matter how I try to access it.

What is the correct way to do this? Is it an anti-pattern to have a property in a singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

So you're struggling to create single instance pojo class with injected @Value. If you can work with bean then this is the way to go:

```
@Component // This will default give you a single ton bean
public class NodeMac {

    @Value("${machine.network.interface}")
    private String networkInterfaceName;

    public String getMacAddress() {
        try {
            NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByName(networkInterfaceName);

            byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

            System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (SocketException | NullPointerException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Failed to extract MAC address for network interface with name " + networkInterfaceName, e);
        }
    }
}
```

**OLD**

How do you come up with this expression:

```
String key = System.getProperty("machine.network.interface");
```

The machine unlikely have only one network interface so there can't be a single key returned.

Indeed, oracle already writes a [tutorial here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    for (NetworkInterface netint : Collections.list(nets))
        displayInterfaceInformation(netint);
}

static void displayInterfaceInformation(NetworkInterface netint) throws SocketException {
    out.printf("Display name: %s\n", netint.getDisplayName());
    out.printf("Name: %s\n", netint.getName());
    Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = netint.getInetAddresses();
    for (InetAddress inetAddress : Collections.list(inetAddresses)) {
        out.printf("InetAddress: %s\n", inetAddress);
    }
    out.printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: The property contains the name of the network interface. In this case `eno1`. I wanted to see if the key was accessible that way, since Springs `@Value` annotation always gives me a null value.

Comment: You cannot. Because your `static` method will run before bean autowiring

Comment: I didn't know singleton was the default, thank you. I only had to remove the static modifier from the value injection in your code above, and now it works.

Comment: Ya, spring bean is `singleton` by default, unless you told it not to be singleton. Glad it helped.